# Unsuccessfully sending a parameter from primefaces page to java bean class

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to send as a parameter an object to a Java class from .xhtml page.

I have the following primefaces dataGrid:

```
<p:dataGrid value="#{userRequestBean.userActiveRequests}" var="userActiveRequest">
            <h:panelGrid>

                <h:commandButton value="Cancel" actionListener="#{userRequestBean.cancelRequest()}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{userRequestBean.request}"
                            value="${userActiveRequest}" />
                </h:commandButton>

            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dataGrid>
```

In my bean I have:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userRequestBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserRequestBean implements Serializable {
    private TRequest request = new TRequest(); // plus get and set methods

    public void cancelRequest (){
        System.out.println("Author name: " + request.geId());
    }
}
```

But it thows me NullPointerException when i press the button. Any idea how i can realize this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <h:commandButton value="Cancel" actionListener="#{userRequestBean.cancelRequest()}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{userRequestBean.request}"
                            value="${userActiveRequest}" />
                </h:commandButton>
```

Why are you using standard-jsf commandButton instead of `Primefaces` button.

To make this work use as :

```
 <p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{userRequestBean.cancelRequest()}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{userRequestBean.request}"
                            value="${userActiveRequest}" />
                </p:commandButton>
```

What we did ?

- Changed to Primefaces commandButton
- Use `action` instead of `actionListener` ( `ActionListener` method should have `ActionEvent` as `parameter`).

I hope above helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using @ViewScoped instead of @SessionScoped. You also have to create getter and setter for request property of your managed bean.

Comment: This has nothing to do with scope.